# Correction only one (specifics) position on array - Python

Tags: python

I`m a new guy trying do a simple code in python to get a  images data set containing 4 bands (R, G, B, Nir) each one. 
For each row (R, G, B only), I need to apply a correction only at some specifics pixels (pixels that representing water on images).
The first step on my code is identify the position (ii,jj) of pixel which is on the water using a other raster files generated using the original images. This raster file used to identify the water has the same size as the raw images.

The condition verified by pixels representing water is:

```py
for ii in range(rows_ndwi):
            for jj in range (cols_ndwi):
                if ndwi[ii,jj] >= 0:
```

Once found the pixels (II, JJ) that need to be corrected in each band, I apply the correction (in each band) only to the pixels located in the water.

At the end of this fix, the array for each band will retain the values that did not have the position identified in the water, and only the pixels located in the water were altered.

I will share the part of my code which "tries" apply these correction.

```py
for i in range(size):
    i += 1
    os.chdir('D:/CESAR_PHD/10.Lyzenga/Test_30/raw_data_rgb_nir/')
    text_file = open('list.txt', 'r') 
    line = text_file.read().split() 
    size = len(line)
    nome = line[i-1]
    ds_res_rgb = gdal.Open(nome)
    rows = ds_res_rgb.RasterYSize
    cols = ds_res_rgb.RasterXSize 
    bands = ds_res_rgb.RasterCount
    print('Opening the red band of image ' + nome)
    banda_red = ds_res_rgb.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)
    print('Opening the green band of image ' + nome)
    banda_green =ds_res_rgb.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)
    print('Opening the blue band of image ' + nome)
    banda_blue =ds_res_rgb.GetRasterBand(3).ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)
       print('Opening the nir band of image ' + nome)
    nir_band = ds_res_rgb.GetRasterBand(3).ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)
    for j in range(size): 
        j += 1
        os.chdir('D:/CESAR_PHD/10.Lyzenga/Test_30/ndwi/')
        text_file_ndwi = open('list.txt', 'r') 
        line_ndwi = text_file_ndwi.read().split()
        size_ndwi = len(line_ndwi)      
        nome_ndwi = line_ndwi[j-1]
        ds_ndwi = gdal.Open(nome_ndwi)
        rows_ndwi = ds_ndwi.RasterYSize
        cols_ndwi = ds_ndwi.RasterXSize
        bands_ndwi = ds_ndwi.RasterCount
        print('Opening NDWI raster file from reservoir ' + nome_ndwi)
        ndwi = ds_ndwi.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols_ndwi, rows_ndwi)
        print('Applyin the sun-glint correction for image ' + nome)
        for ii in range(rows_ndwi):
            for jj in range (cols_ndwi):
                if ndwi[ii,jj] >= 0: ## condition for found the positions for pixels that need to be correction
                    banda_red[ii,jj] = (banda_red[ii,jj] - (a[0] * (nir_band[ii,jj] - nir_dw)))
                    banda_green[ii,jj] = (banda_green[ii,jj] - (a[1] * (nir_band[ii,jj] - nir_dw)))
                    banda_blue[ii,jj] = (banda_blue[ii,jj] - (a[2] * (nir_band[ii,jj] - nir_dw)))
```

Comment: So what part of your code isn't working, exactly?

Comment: The corrections applied for each band. When I will see the raster files "corrected" I didn`t see any correction on the pixels on the water. I have thought that the correction has being doing only the last pixel identified on the water.

Comment: Are you saving and closing the image after making the modifications to it (I see `gdal.Open()` but not `ds_ndwi.Close()` or anything similar)? If not those modifications might not be getting applied.